# jQuery set a class to all divs except nth-child

Tags: jquery

Im trying to hide all divs of a class apart from the first one when the first element is selected in a select list. I thought that line 4 would override line 3 but it doesnt appear to be working this way.

```
function myFunction() {
  if (jQuery('#select').val() == '1') {
    jQuery('.mydiv').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('.mydiv(1)').removeClass('hide');
  }
}
```

UPDATE - the various div.mydiv's may already have the hide class, so the code needs to make sure only the 1st instance has the class. The other divs need to have the class removed if they have it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ should help you here

Comment: use the `:not()` and `:nth-child()` selectors, or the `:gt()` selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to all, filter to first, and remove the class.

```
function myFunction() {
  if (jQuery('#select').val() == '1') {
    jQuery('.mydiv').addClass('hide').first().removeClass("hide");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll delete my comments as they're not relevant now the question, and your answer, have changed :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution, it allows you only to skip the first element

Comment: @bukfixart I agree, but without further instruction as far as the intent of the code in the question, anything more would be speculation. `.first()` would be the same as `.filter(":eq(0)")` then if you wanted to select a specific element that wasn't first, increment 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$(".mydiv:not(:nth-child(1))").addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just exclude the n-th child

```
jQuery( '.mydiv' ).not( ':eq(1)' ).addClass( 'hide' );
```